# React: Custom component not representing the right data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-props, react-state-management

I am facing a weird problem now.
I have a list of tasks which are coming via rest api.
I created a custom card component to display it.

```
    /* eslint-disable import/first */
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import Grid from 'material-ui/Grid';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import List, { ListItem, ListItemIcon, ListItemText } from 'material-ui/List';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
import Card, { CardActions, CardContent } from 'material-ui/Card';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import { LinearProgress } from 'material-ui/Progress';

import Modal from 'react-responsive-modal';

var Moment = require('moment');

import TaskActions from '../redux/TaskRedux'
import ProgressColumn from './Progress'
import TaskCard from './Card'
import AddTaskCard from './AddTaskCard'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import '../styles/main.css';


export class Container extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            fetching: this.props.fetching,
            taskName: null,
            showError: false,
            openEditModal: false,
            editTaskName: null,
            showUpdateError: false,
            toBeUpdatedTask: null,
            progressTasks:[],
            tasks: []
        }

    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getTasks()
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if(prevProps !== this.props){
            this.setState({fetching: this.props.fetching, 
            tasks: this.props.tasks})
        }
    }

    render(){
        let {fetching, progressTasks} = this.state
        let {tasks} = this.props
        if(tasks)
            tasks.map(i => console.log(i.title))
        return (
            <div className="grid-root">

                <Grid container spacing={24}>
                    <Grid item xs={3} sm={3}>
                        <Paper className="task-list-view">
                            <List className="task-list">
                                {tasks && tasks.map((item,i) => (
                                    <ListItem key={`item-${i}`}>
                                        <TaskCard task={item} key={`item-${i}`}/>
                                    </ListItem>
                                ))}
                            </List>
                            <AddTaskCard/>
                        </Paper>
                        {fetching ? (<LinearProgress color="secondary" />): ('')}
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={3} sm={3}>
                        <Paper className="task-list-view">
                            <ProgressColumn progressTasks={progressTasks}/>
                        </Paper>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      fetching: state.task.fetching,
      tasks: state.task.tasks,
    }
  }

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getTasks: () => dispatch(TaskActions.fetchTasks()),
        deleteTask: (taskId) => dispatch(TaskActions.deleteTask(taskId)),
        updateTask: (taskId,title) => dispatch(TaskActions.updateTask(taskId,title)),
    }
  }

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Container)
```

Here is the card component:

```
/* eslint-disable import/first */

import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import Card, { CardActions, CardContent } from 'material-ui/Card';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';

import TaskActions from '../redux/TaskRedux'
import EditModal from './EditModal'

var Moment = require('moment');


export class TaskCard extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            openEditModal: false,
            editTaskName: null,
            task: this.props.task
        }

    }

    // handle edit of task name
    handleTaskEdit(task){
        console.log("edit task", task)
        // this.setState({openEditModal: true, editTaskName: task.title, toBeUpdatedTask: task})
        this.props.editTask(task)
    }

    // handle start task button click
    // Will push the tasks for progressTasks state
    handleStartTask(task){
        // this.setState({
        //     progressTasks: [...this.state.progressTasks, task]
        // })
    }

    // handle deletion of the task
    handleTaskDelete(taskId){
        console.log(taskId)
        this.props.deleteTask(taskId)
        // this.props.getTasks()
    }


    render(){
        let {task} = this.state
        let created = Moment(task.created).format("Do MMM YYYY")
        console.log("task", task)
        return (
            <Card className="task-card" key={task.id}>
                <EditModal/>
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography variant="headline" component="h2">
                        {task.title}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography color="textSecondary">
                        {created}
                    </Typography>
                </CardContent>
                <CardActions>
                    <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={this.handleTaskEdit.bind(this, task)}>Edit</Button>
                    <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={this.handleStartTask.bind(this, task)}>Start Task</Button>
                    <Button size="small" color="secondary" onClick={this.handleTaskDelete.bind(this, task.id)}>Delete</Button>
                </CardActions>
            </Card>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {

    }
  }

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getTasks: () => dispatch(TaskActions.fetchTasks()),
        deleteTask: (taskId) => dispatch(TaskActions.deleteTask(taskId)),
        editTask: (currentTask) => dispatch(TaskActions.editTask(currentTask))
    }
  }

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TaskCard)
```

When I delete a task from top or bottom, it updates fine, but when I do it from the middle, the bottom one disappears and the one intended to be deleted still stays/shows. When you refresh it, than of course all is fine, but the question is, why does this happen? I have a redux saga, which fetches the tasks again after delete action, and I could confirm that props do get the right data too.

### UPDATE 1

So, I tried to debug it from my end. Looks like the TaskCard is somewhat caching the props. 
[image]

In the image where `{item.title}` is added and just beneath is where TaskCard is rendered, both have different title but `{item.title}` is right.

### Update 2

Based on jmathew, answer, I updated the key of ListItem and TaskCard to item.id, so delete works, but update still doesnt work. Again, as per Update 1, it still shows wrong title but the {item.title} is right. 
So, that part of the code now looks like:

```
                <List className="task-list">
                    {tasks && tasks.map((item,i) => (
                        <ListItem key={item.id}>
                            {item.title}
                            <TaskCard item={item} key= 
              {`item-${item.id}`}/>
                        </ListItem>
                    ))}
                </List>
```

### Update 3

New TaskCard component:

```
/* eslint-disable import/first */

import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import Card, { CardActions, CardContent } from 'material-ui/Card';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';

import TaskActions from '../redux/TaskRedux'
import EditModal from './EditModal'

var Moment = require('moment');


export class TaskCard extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            openEditModal: false,
            editTaskName: null,
            item: this.props.item
        }

    }

    // handle edit of task name
    handleTaskEdit(task){
        console.log("edit task", task)
        // this.setState({openEditModal: true, editTaskName: task.title, toBeUpdatedTask: task})
        this.props.editTask(task)
    }

    // handle start task button click
    // Will push the tasks for progressTasks state
    handleStartTask(task){
        // this.setState({
        //     progressTasks: [...this.state.progressTasks, task]
        // })
    }

    // handle deletion of the task
    handleTaskDelete(taskId){
        // console.log(taskId)
        this.props.deleteTask(taskId)
        // this.props.getTasks()
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot){
        console.log("update ", prevProps, prevState)
    }

    render(){
        let {item} = this.state
        let created = Moment(item.created).format("Do MMM YYYY")
        console.log("item",item)
        return (
            <Card className="task-card" key={`task-${item.id}`}>
                <EditModal/>
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography variant="headline" component="h2">
                        {item.title}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography color="textSecondary">
                        {created}
                    </Typography>
                </CardContent>
                <CardActions>
                    <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={this.handleTaskEdit.bind(this, item)}>Edit</Button>
                    <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={this.handleStartTask.bind(this, item)}>Start Task</Button>
                    <Button size="small" color="secondary" onClick={this.handleTaskDelete.bind(this, item.id)}>Delete</Button>
                </CardActions>
            </Card>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
    }
  }

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getTasks: () => dispatch(TaskActions.fetchTasks()),
        deleteTask: (taskId) => dispatch(TaskActions.deleteTask(taskId)),
        editTask: (currentTask) => dispatch(TaskActions.editTask(currentTask))
    }
  }

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TaskCard)
```

[image]

As you can see in the pic above, the title next to card is the updated one, which is triggered by edit button, but that same thing is not passed on to TaskCard component. In the screenshot, there is a console output, there the line "update " shows that the change has not triggered componentDidUpdate.

Comment: can you post the deleteTask action code

Comment: It is not a problem of that at all. I have verified it, the problem is right where the TaskCard component is called in Container component.

Comment: Ok, can you try to use task from props instead of state in TaskCard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be a combination of key and use of state in child component. Since you are using index as the key, if you delete the item from the middle, the index to data render mapping changes and the cards are re-rendered with different props, however, you are not updating the state in taskCard so the data doesn't change. setting state which is directly derivable from props isn't the right way and if you do that, you need to also update state in response to prop change

To solve the issue all you need to do is to render the task from state

```
 export class TaskCard extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            openEditModal: false,
            editTaskName: null,
        }

    }

    // handle edit of task name
    handleTaskEdit(task){
        console.log("edit task", task)
        // this.setState({openEditModal: true, editTaskName: task.title, toBeUpdatedTask: task})
        this.props.editTask(task)
    }

    // handle start task button click
    // Will push the tasks for progressTasks state
    handleStartTask(task){
        // this.setState({
        //     progressTasks: [...this.state.progressTasks, task]
        // })
    }

    // handle deletion of the task
    handleTaskDelete(taskId){
        console.log(taskId)
        this.props.deleteTask(taskId)
        // this.props.getTasks()
    }


    render(){
        let {task} = this.props;
        let created = Moment(task.created).format("Do MMM YYYY")
        console.log("task", task)
        return (
            <Card className="task-card" key={task.id}>
                <EditModal/>
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography variant="headline" component="h2">
                        {task.title}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography color="textSecondary">
                        {created}
                    </Typography>
                </CardContent>
                <CardActions>
                    <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={this.handleTaskEdit.bind(this, task)}>Edit</Button>
                    <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={this.handleStartTask.bind(this, task)}>Start Task</Button>
                    <Button size="small" color="secondary" onClick={this.handleTaskDelete.bind(this, task.id)}>Delete</Button>
                </CardActions>
            </Card>
        )
    }
}
```

However using item id which is unique will improve the performance.

Comment: Thanks, based on jmathew suggestion, now I am using item.id check my update 2, so, delete works fine,  BUT update is not working, well, it doesnt update the updated name straight away.

Comment: @Maverick, please use task from props instead of state. check my answer

Comment: Subham, yes I did that, let me put the new card component in update 3.

Answer (score 1):

Your symptoms are consistent with an issue with the `key` prop on your `ListItem`. It looks like you're using the index in the array when you need something unique to the backing data.

Before you call delete react sees a VDOM with the keys `1, 2, 3, 4`. Then you hit delete on `3`. Now re-render gets called and you use `i` to regenerate the keys. The new keys are `1, 2, 3`. React diffs the previous DOM with the new one and sees that only `4` is missing and removes it.

The solution to your update problem can be solved in one of two ways:

1. Use props instead of state in your render. This is the preferred
   choice as it's simpler. `let {item} = this.state` > `let {item} =
   this.props` (as per Shubham's answer).
2. Implement componentDidUpdate. If you still want to keep item in
   state you need to make sure it is updated when the parent component
   sends your component new props:

It might look like this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState) {
    if(this.props.item != this.state.item) {
        this.setState( { item: this.props.item });
    }
}
```

Comment: I read it somewhere, but the key is assigned a value i, which is iterator autoincrement. So, should I try item.id?

Comment: yup that should do it.

Comment: An alternative is to use some unique combination of the data in item if you do not have an `Id` on the data.

Comment: yeah, absolutely. Only ever make `key` point to something that is uniquely identifying to your data, never use list positions. If that value is long, perfect. data.name, or data.title are usually great candidates.

Comment: Please check my update 2, yes, you suggestion worked for delete, but not for update.

Comment: When a component is recycled instead of re-created (like in an update), react calls `componentDidUpdate`. You should try implementing that method and setting state if the new props are different from the current state. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: Nope, it wont help. I will put an image to explain. @jmathew check the image in the end.

Comment: I'm not sure if it was a typo but in your update 3 you've not used props like Shubham suggested. Also in the `componentDidUpdate` you need to `console.log(this.props)` which is the updated version, the prevProps are provided for comparison.

Comment: And to be clear either one of our suggestions ( using props instead of state or implementing componentDidUpdate) should solve it. I recommend the props method because its simpler.

Comment: I specifically mean this line in your `render()` `let {item} = this.state` should be `let {item} = this.props`.